# Using custom ArrayAdapter in Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

In my android application I need to use a Dialog Fragment in order to show some clickable imageViews and select a color, which will be used by the main activity, but I've got a problem with my code.
I've created a custom ArrayAdapter, which takes ColorCircle class as a reference. Here is the ArrayAdapter

```
public class ColorCircleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

Context context;
int resource;
ColorCircle [] objects;

public ColorCircleAdapter(Context context, int resource, ColorCircle[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.objects = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View row = convertView;
    ColorCircleHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

        holder = new ColorCircleHolder();
        holder.circleIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon_color);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ColorCircleHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    ColorCircle singleCircle = objects[position];
    holder.circleIcon.setImageResource(singleCircle.icon);

    return row;
}

static class ColorCircleHolder{
    ImageView circleIcon;
}
```

And here is the code I use inside onCreateDialog

```
lertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    ColorCircle [] colorCircles = new ColorCircle[] {
            new ColorCircle(R.drawable.blu)
    };
    ColorCircleAdapter adapter = new ColorCircleAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.color_view, colorCircles);
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_color_dialog, null);
    ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.color_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color)
            .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mListener.onListElementSelected(ColorDialogFragment.this,which);
                }
            });
        return builder.create();
```

But it doesn't work, the application crashes as I click on the icon that should open the dialog. Is there something I am missing on the workflow? Is it possible that when I debug it never enters the overridden getView?
Here are the errors I get

```
thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418b4d40)
 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:249)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:234)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:361)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:262)
            at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:493)
            at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1724)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:918)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Error is `requestFeature() must be called before adding content` but I don't see `requestFeature()` in your code!!

Comment: are you calling requestfeature in oncreate?

Comment: I dont see any, builder.setView(view);
Did you even set the view?

Comment: I followed the android guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DialogFragment) and that's why you don't see requestFeature

Comment: This is what the guide say @Carnal
"To provide a layout for a fragment, you must implement the onCreateView() callback method, which the Android system calls when it's time for the fragment to draw its layout. Your implementation of this method must return a View that is the root of your fragment's layout."
- which I did

Comment: Also, when I put an array of string in onCreateDialog and use setItems, it works

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your adapter code. Exception is occurring in `requestfeature()`. It should be called in this manner:

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    //HERE
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu); 
}
```

Comment: Is it normal that requestWindowFeature and setContentView is not recognized by onCreate?

Comment: If you put requestWindowFeature after super.oncreate() method then it will throw error

Comment: No, I've put it before super.onCreate() method, as you suggested

Comment: Nope. requestWindowFeature and setContentView are not recognized